# Python pandas convert rows to columns where multiple columns exist

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a DF with multiple columns which I want to convert from rows to columns most solutions I have seen on stack overflow only deal with 2 columns

> From DF

```
PO ID   PO Name Region  Date    Price
1       AA      North   07/2016 100
2       BB      South   07/2016 200
1       AA      North   08/2016 300
2       BB      South   08/2016 400
1       AA      North   09/2016 500
```

> To DF

```
PO ID   PO Name Region  07/2016 08/2016 09/2016
1       AA      North   100     300     500
2       BB      South   200     400     NaN
```

Comment: this is called pivoting or unstacking. lots questions already on SO about this

Comment: oh..okay I did a search on convert rows to columns most questions dealt with only 2 columns and since I had multiple columns. Any how will read more before posting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['PO ID','PO Name','Region', 'Date'])['Price'].unstack()
print (df)
Date                  07/2016  08/2016  09/2016
PO ID PO Name Region                           
1     AA      North     100.0    300.0    500.0
2     BB      South     200.0    400.0      NaN
```

If duplicates need aggregate function with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or `groupby`:

```
print (df)
   PO ID PO Name Region     Date  Price
0      1      AA  North  07/2016    100 <-for PO ID;PO Name;Region;Date different Price
1      1      AA  North  07/2016    500 <-for PO ID;PO Name;Region;Date different Price
2      2      BB  South  07/2016    200
3      1      AA  North  08/2016    300
4      2      BB  South  08/2016    400
5      1      AA  North  09/2016    500

df = df.pivot_table(index=['PO ID','PO Name','Region'], 
                    columns='Date', 
                    values='Price', 
                    aggfunc='mean')
print (df)
Date                  07/2016  08/2016  09/2016
PO ID PO Name Region                           
1     AA      North     300.0    300.0    500.0 <-(100+500)/2=300 for 07/2016
2     BB      South     200.0    400.0      NaN
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['PO ID','PO Name','Region', 'Date'])['Price'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
Date                  07/2016  08/2016  09/2016
PO ID PO Name Region                           
1     AA      North     300.0    300.0    500.0 <-(100+500)/2=300 for 07/2016
2     BB      South     200.0    400.0      NaN
```

Last:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   PO ID PO Name Region  07/2016  08/2016  09/2016
0      1      AA  North    300.0    300.0    500.0
1      2      BB  South    200.0    400.0      NaN
```

Comment: I tried the 3rd solution of groupby as set_index on the actual data had duplicate entires

Comment: And some problem? If yes, can you explain more?

Comment: 3rd solution worked perfectly fine. 1st solution got the error.   ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Super, 3rd solution is fastest if duplicates. Nice day!