# Can I use machine learning on below dataset sample

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

[Dataset Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYwU2.png)

Can I use any algorithm to train above dataset ? 
Because Each Row (Id) has Dependent Variable(Status) . But Each "Id" again as Mulitple Rows as per Features
You Can Assume it as "Each Id has multiple transaction and All transactions have common Status"
Will Machine learning find some Patterns from these transaction

Is there any other approach to solve these type of problems

Comment: Please read the description for the [tag:ml] tag one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fill your ID row with the value from the above row , same for the status row, this will lead to:

```
df
ID Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Status
8079 100    Asia      High    Approved
8079 200    Africa    Low     Approved
```

When you run a classification algorithm, you can use: `ID, Feature1, Feature2, Feature3`as features and Status as target. A classifier will learn with this and everything is completly the same as before.
The features are still independet. Dependet features you will only have if the variables are somehow dependet to each other, in your case the ID 8079 does not lead to Feature1: Africa. They are independet.

You can fill your cells with:

```
import numpy as np
df[df[0]==""] = np.NaN
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Based on your comments, the approach can be slightly different, you need to convert your entries to new features ([Python pandas convert rows to columns where multiple columns exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453162/python-pandas-convert-rows-to-columns-where-multiple-columns-exist)):
The dataframe then should look like:

```
ID Feature1 Feature2 Feature3  Feature1a .... Feature3z Status
8079 100    Asia      High    200                       Approved
```

Comment: Each Id has multiple transaction (3 Rows) . Now there is some Logic made behind these grouping of Transaction and these logic helps in Status field in Prev System.I Iwant to replace it with ML so that it can be automated for future . So it is neccessary for me to Treat these transactions as One Tuple .So that My prev System Logic Remains in my new System

Comment: then you need to transform the rows, that you have 9 features per ID

Comment: After considering Every transaction for each id . Decision of Status Field is made

Comment: In some id's . I have 5 transactions in some of them there are 20 transaction .

Comment: In some of them there 50-60 transactions

Comment: then you need to map several features to it

Comment: So I need to First Find which Id has Maximum Transactions.And then create that many columns . i-e 100(Max) ,Then there will be[  100*3(Features)  = 300 ] columns for each tuple.

Comment: There might be a case where in one of my ID there is Only One Transaction . Then [1 * 3(features) -> 3 columns ] . So rest of the Columns out 300 will be 0. (300-3 = 297 )

Comment: The 0 are no problem, and there are codes to automatically convert that rows to columns...

Comment: So if I automatically convert these rows into columns .Then Column name will be automatically created right ?. Can you provide me some more details of converting these rows into new columns as features

Comment: Is it Correct Approach ?  Because 1000 features are created for each ID.And for some id if there is only one row in dataset . Then in rest of columns it is Zero.So is it OK to have zeros in dataset .

Comment: will it cause "Curse of dimensionality" ?

Comment: Will it lead to Over fitting because there are large no of features

Comment: Over fitting you can test with train/test split :)

Answer (score 0):

you can either assume that each row is independent and ignore the `id` column or if every ID has 3 rows, you could extend the dataset with more features

Comment: But I want these Each 3 Rows of EveryId as Feature. Because It will generate some pattern which will be helpful in Prediction of status

Comment: Assume every row of Id as Transactions of that id , And there are some patterns which will be identified Once we group all transactions