# Import an exported grafana csv file into python pandas that makes sense?

Tags: python, pandas, grafana

The title of this question could probably use some work. But here is what I'm wanting to do. I have exported data from a grafana dashboard. It turns out to be something like

```
    Series  Time    Value
0   A   2020-11-11 21:00:00-05:00   0.003020
1   A   2020-11-11 21:00:30-05:00   0.050300
2   A   2020-11-11 21:01:00-05:00   0.080000
3   A   2020-11-11 21:01:30-05:00   0.000900
4   A   2020-11-11 21:02:00-05:00   0.004000
....
    Series  Time    Value
0   B   2020-11-11 21:00:00-05:00   0.004070
1   B   2020-11-11 21:00:30-05:00   0.002080
2   B   2020-11-11 21:01:00-05:00   0.004030
3   B   2020-11-11 21:01:30-05:00   0.005040
4   B   2020-11-11 21:02:00-05:00   0.006060
```

What I would like to do is import the data and translate it to something that is makes sense with pandas. Something like...

```
    Time    Series_A    Series_B
0  2020-11-11 2121:00:00-05:00  0.003020    0.004070
1  2020-11-11 2121:00:30-05:00  0.050300    0.002080
2  2020-11-11 2121:01:00-05:00  0.080000    0.004030
3  2020-11-11 2121:01:30-05:00  0.000900    0.005040
4  2020-11-11 2121:02:00-05:00  0.004000    0.006060
```

This allows for graphs to be easily created between the to different set of Series.

Answer (score 1):

With some additional searching I finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453162/python-pandas-convert-rows-to-columns-where-multiple-columns-exist).

Using the pivot_table made it easy.

```py
table.pivot_table(index=['Time'], columns='Series', values='Value')
```